# flutter downgrade error - There is no previously recorded version for channel

Tags: flutter

My project uses packages that are not backward compatible,

I tired to install on a new PC but it install the latest flutter and I cannot downgrade flutter

```
$ flutter downgrade v1.22.6
Downloading Dart SDK from Flutter engine a252ec09b74cca0f8d8d3450566bf77c77f81e8d...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  199M  100  199M    0     0  1159k      0  0:02:55  0:02:55 --:--:-- 2695k
Building flutter tool...
Downloading Material fonts...                                    1,453ms
Downloading Gradle Wrapper...                                      242ms
Downloading package sky_engine...                                  914ms
Downloading flutter_patched_sdk tools...                            4.8s
Downloading flutter_patched_sdk_product tools...                    3.9s
Downloading linux-x64 tools...                                      7.3s
Downloading linux-x64/font-subset tools...                         874ms
There is no previously recorded version for channel "dev".
```

I tried on `stable` and `beta` as well

```
$ flutter downgrade v1.22.6
There is no previously recorded version for channel "stable".

flutter downgrade 1.22.6
There is no previously recorded version for channel "beta".
```

I also tried:

```
$ flutter version v1.22.6
WARNING: Flutter version command has been removed, using latest from channel
```

Answer (score 76):

cd to flutter directory, e.g. `/home/elia/snap/flutter/common/flutter`

then do:

`git checkout 1.22.6`

Comment: Approve this, is working like a charm!

Comment: Shouldn't `flutter downgrade` do this automatically? Or at least, provide a better error message.

Comment: @xip For me `flutter downgrade` was just giving error message: `There is no previously recorded version for channel "stable".`.

Comment: 2024, this method worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You can download the version you want from the [Flutter SDK release page](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases) then install it as your Flutter SDK on your machine.[image]

Answer (score 7):

1. open flutter SDK directory on terminal, and type `git checkout <sdk-version>` e.g `git checkout 2.5.0`. just make sure the version you are asking for is correct as in the sdk documentation (https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/releases).
2. Type `flutter --version`. if terminal dispaying something like `Downloading Dart SDK from Flutter engine . . .` means you just have to wait for the download update to finish.
3. when download has finish, type again `flutter --version` to make sure that the sdk has changed.
4. finish.

Answer (score 7):

The `flutter downgrade` command was not working.

[image: There is no previously recorded version for channel "stable".]

**Steps to fix this:**

- Navigate to your installation of Flutter.

  Flutter on my device was installed under `documents` in a folder called `development`.
  [image: navigate to flutter installation]
- Run the `git checkout <version>` command

  You can check out the different version names *[here](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/releases)*.
  [image]
- Finally, run `flutter --version`.

  This will download the specified version of Flutter.
  [image]

Answer (score 5):

Go to your flutter install folder. If you do not know installation path, use this command:

```
flutter sdk-path
```

Then use git to downgrade

```
git checkout <VERSION>
flutter --version
```

This will download the specified version and downgrade flutter.

Comment: I get this: Could not find a command named "sdk-path".

Answer (score 3):

Check your flutter channel:

> flutter channel

Show like this:

Flutter channels:
master
dev
beta

- stable
  Change to master:

> flutter channel master

Run command:

> flutter downgrade v1.22.6

Answer (score 1):

Download the version you want from the  Flutter sdk release page and select that SDK path in `Settings> Language and Framework > Flutter` .

If it throws the error " the flutter sdk is incomplete.."  Simply navigate to where you downloaded the SDK then `Flutter> Bin> Flutter.bat`

This will download the remaining files for the sdk. You can then select the sdk path without error

[SDK Release page](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases)

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is: Download the version of Flutter you need and put it in the place where Flutter is installed In this directory you have "flutter" folder.

In Ubuntu, it is usually located in this path: /home/username/development/flutter

To develop the software with the desired version, just change the desired folder name to "flutter".

For example :

flutter --> flutter-3.x.x

flutter-2.x.x ---> flutter

The Stable channel contains the most stable Flutter builds: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/releases?tab=linux

Answer (score -1):

Clone the flutter git hub repository

*git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git*

checkout to your preferred branch

*git checkout **flutter version***

Answer (score -2):

this works for me.

```
flutter downgrade <VERSION>
eg: flutter downgrade 1.22.6
```

Comment: @MarkRotteveel uh, he is not posting "thank you" as an answer, he is providing an actual answer.

Comment: @user1032613 It isn't an answer, because the OP states in their question that they tried this exact command. But yes, maybe I shouldn't have selected this reason in the review queue.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Ah, you are right, I didn't notice OP mentioned it.